# Series expansion in terms of Hermite polynomials

Tags: functions, polynomials, special-functions, series-expansion

I am trying to expand a polynomial in terms of orthogonal polynomials (in my case, Hermite). Maple has a nice built-in function for this, [`ChangeBasis`](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=OrthogonalSeries/ChangeBasis).

Is there a similar function in *Mathematica*? And if not, where should I look for the algorithm?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Hermite polynomials are orthogonal with respect to the inner product
$$\langle f,g \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)g(x)e^{-x^2} \, \mathrm dx.$$
Thus, the $n$-th coefficient can be computed using the inner product of your polynomial with the $n$-th normalized Hermite polynomial.

Example:

```
p[x_] = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3;
coeffs = Table[
  Integrate[HermiteH[n, x]*p[x]*Exp[-x^2], {x, -∞, ∞}]/
   Integrate[HermiteH[n, x]^2*Exp[-x^2], {x, -∞, ∞}],
  {n, 0, 3}]
(* Out: {3/2, 5/4, 1/4, 1/8} *)

coeffs.Table[HermiteH[n, x], {n, 0, 3}] // Expand
(* Out: 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 *)
```

Answer (score 14):

For polynomials, you don't need to do any integrals to find the expansion. Take a polynomial `p` and a list `basis` containing the basis functions. Then define a function that takes these two, identifies the variable `x`, and solves for the coefficients in `basis` that make the two polynomials equal in terms of their `CoefficientList`s:

```
expandPoly[p_, basis_, x_] :=
# /. First@Solve[CoefficientList[#.basis, x] == #2, #] &[
     Array["a", Length[#]], #] & @
     PadRight[CoefficientList[p, x], Length[basis]]

expandPoly[1 + x + 3 x^2 + 7 x^3, HermiteH[Range[4] - 1, x], x]

(* ==> {5/2, 23/4, 3/4, 7/8} *)
```

**Edit**

In response to belisarius: if you already know that you're only interested in a basis of `HermiteH`, you could incorporate that into the function and do away with the specification of the variable `basis` as follows:

```
expandPoly[p_, x_] := # /. 
      First @ Solve[
        CoefficientList[#.HermiteH[Range[Length[#]] - 1, x], 
          x] == #2, #] &[Array["a", Length[#]], #] & @ CoefficientList[p, x]

expandPoly[1 + x + 3 x^2 + 7 x^3, x]

(* ==> {5/2, 23/4, 3/4, 7/8} *)
```

**Edit 2**

With the general function given as the first solution above, you can specify any set of polynomials that is known to form a basis for degree `n` or larger. This means the basis functions don't have to be orthogonal polynomials at all.

Comment: (+1) Very nice.  I was just doing similar thing with another problem, but didn't think of it here.

Comment: How to get rid of that _Range@4_?

Comment: @belisarius See edit - I hardcoded the `HermiteH` part into the function in case you're only interested in those basis functions. Then the counting of terms is automatic. In the first version, I wanted to keep the list `basis` deliberately general so you can use other polynomials there, too.

Comment: Ahh... Algebra.  I accidentally studied analysis in graduate school. :)

Comment: If the expansion is known finite, one should be able to manage the upper bound automagically.

Comment: @belisarius That's what my second version does. Or are you referring to the case of a more general basis?

Comment: @Jens I was referring to a general basis, but the ordering issues can't be solved, so I guess one should iterate until the poly is fully expressed

Comment: @belisarius For that general case, at least I can allow a larger basis than necessary, with the latest edit. Then `basis` can be kept fixed as some list with a number of polynomials that is expected to be large enough for all purposes.

Answer (score 9):

The inner product for the Hermite polynomials,
$$\langle f, g\rangle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\,g(x)\,e^{-x^2}\;dx\,,$$
has nice formulas for power functions (where $n=a+b$) and for the Hermite polynomials:
$$
\begin{align}
\langle x^a, x^b \rangle = \langle x^n, 1\rangle &= \frac{1}{2} \left((-1)^n+1\right)\, \Gamma
   \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)\cr
\langle H_n(x), H_n(x) \rangle &= \sqrt{\pi}\,2^n n! \cr
\end{align}
$$

These can be used to give a quick change of basis function for polynomials.

```
hermiteIP[f_, g_, x_] := With[{coeff = CoefficientList[f g, x]},
   coeff.Table[1/2 (1 + (-1)^(-1 + n)) Gamma[n/2], {n, Length@coeff}]];

hermiteExpand[poly_, var_] /; PolynomialQ[poly, var] :=
 Sum[hermiteIP[poly, HermiteH[n, var], var] H[n, var]/(Sqrt[Pi] 2^n n!),
  {n, 0, Exponent[poly, var]}]
```

I used `H[n, x]` as a place holder for `HermiteH[n, x]`.

```
hermiteExpand[(1 + x)^5, x]
(* 39/4 H[0, x] + 95/8 H[1, x] + 25/4 H[2, x] + 15/8 H[3, x] + 
    5/16 H[4, x] + 1/32 H[5, x]  *)

hermiteExpand[(1 + x)^5, x] /. H -> HermiteH
(* 39/4 H[0, x] + 95/8 H[1, x] + 25/4 H[2, x] + 15/8 H[3, x] + 
    5/16 H[4, x] + 1/32 H[5, x]  *)

% // Factor
(* (1 + x)^5 *)
```

Comment: Probably the best answer. It uses the orthogonality and speeds things up using the closed form. +1

Answer (score 5):

Whenever I want to convert some polynomial expressed with respect to a certain basis in terms of another polynomial basis. my go-to algorithm is [Salzer's algorithm](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/355611.362548). It's rather fast, since it relies only on recurrences. Here's a specialization of that algorithm for the case of monomial-Hermite conversion:

```
monomialToHermite[cofs_?VectorQ] := Module[{n = Length[cofs] - 1, a},
  a[0, 0] = cofs[[n + 1]]; a[0, 1] = cofs[[n]]; 
  a[1, 1] = cofs[[n + 1]]/2;
  Do[
     a[0, k + 1] = cofs[[n - k]] + a[1, k];
     Do[
        a[m, k + 1] = (m + 1) a[m + 1, k] + a[m - 1, k]/2,
        {m, k - 1}];
     a[k, k + 1] = a[k - 1, k]/2; a[k + 1, k + 1] = a[k, k]/2,
     {k, n - 1}];
  Table[a[m, n], {m, 0, n}]]
```

The algorithm as I presented it here uses an implicit two-dimensional array, `a`, to clearly show off the recurrence. The algorithm can be easily rewritten so that it uses only a pair or so of one-dimensional arrays, but I'll leave out that version for now.

Here's a test of Salzer's method:

```
monomialToHermite[{1, 1, 3, 7}]
   {5/2, 23/4, 3/4, 7/8}

{1, 1, 3, 7}.x^Range[0, 3] == {5/2, 23/4, 3/4, 7/8}.HermiteH[Range[0, 3], x] // Expand
   True

CoefficientList[(1 + x)^5, x] // monomialToHermite
   {39/4, 95/8, 25/4, 15/8, 5/16, 1/32}

%.HermiteH[Range[0, 5], x] == (1 + x)^5 // Expand
   True
```

(Other instances where I used Salzer's algorithm include [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/51741) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/145747).)

Comment: (Of course, the algorithm is easily implemented even in languages that don't have symbolic capabilities.)

Comment: Late answers are usually underestimated, +2.

Comment: Can't argue with that. Thanks @Artes!

Comment: @seb, to clarify: are you expecting the terms of such an expansion to then come out as something like $c_{jk}H_j(x)H_k(y)$?

Comment: J.M., sorry for the unfortunate timing. I deleted my comment, because I remembered that this part is not the bottleneck in my calculation. But yes, I want expressions of the form $c_{kl} H_k(x)H_l(y)$. (In fact this is an XY problem and in the end I'm only interested at the values at $x=y=0$.)

Comment: @seb, and that's just the constant term, no? ;)

Comment: Well... yeah :)

Comment: J.M., I think I misunderstood you. I need $c_{kl}H_k(0)H_l(0)$ for all $j,k$ separately, not their sum (and thus the constant term of the original polynomial).

Answer (score 5):

[`SolveAlways`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SolveAlways.html) can find coordinates of a polynomial with respect to any given basis.  You set up an equation, setting the given polynomial equal to a linear combination of your basis polynomials.  This approach will work generally with any polynomial that is a linear combination of a given set of (linearly independent) polynomials.

```
poly = 1 + x + 3 x^2 + 7 x^3;       (* Jens' example *)

params = Table[C[i], {i, 0, Exponent[poly, x]}];
basis = HermiteH[Range[0, Exponent[poly, x]], x];

coeff = params /. First@SolveAlways[poly == params.basis, x]
(*  {5/2, 23/4, 3/4, 7/8}  *)
```

**Update: Extension to ChangeBasis**

Here is a version of the Maple [`ChangeBasis`](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=OrthogonalSeries/ChangeBasis) that works on polynomials (but not on infinite sums).  It is based on the above idea.

```
ClearAll[changeBasis];
changeBasis[poly_, basisfamilies : {_, _} ..] := 
 Module[{vars, families, degrees, params, basis, coeff},
  vars = {basisfamilies}[[All, 1]];
  families = {basisfamilies}[[All, 2]];
  degrees = Exponent[poly, vars];
  params = Outer[C, ##] & @@ (Range[0, #] &) /@ degrees;
  basis =
   With[{bfn = Times @@ MapThread[#1[#3, #2] &,
                               {families, vars, Array[Slot, Length[vars]]}]},
    Outer[HoldForm[bfn] &, ##] & @@ (Range[0, #] &) /@ degrees
    ];
  coeff = params /. First@SolveAlways[
      poly == Total[params*ReleaseHold@basis, -1], vars];
  With[{res = Total[coeff*basis, -1]},
   Hold[res] /. HoldForm[v_] :> v
   ]
  ]
```

Some examples from the Maple docs.  `GegenbauerC[n, 1, x]` is automatically simplified to `ChebyshevU[n, x]`, which affect the form of the output.

```
changeBasis[1 + 2 x + 3 x^3, {x, GegenbauerC[#1, 1, #2] &}]
ReleaseHold[%] // Expand
GegenbauerC[n, 1, x]        (* Same as ChebyshevU[n, x] *)
(* 
  Hold[ChebyshevU[0, x] + 7/4 ChebyshevU[1, x] + 3/8 ChebyshevU[3, x]]

  1 + 2 x + 3 x^3
  ChebyshevU[n, x]
*)
```

Multivariable function:

```
changeBasis[y^2 + x^2 - 1, {x, LaguerreL[#1, 1, #2] &}, {y, ChebyshevU}]
ReleaseHold[%] // Expand
(*
  Hold[21/4 (ChebyshevU[0, y] LaguerreL[0, 1, x]) + 
      1/4 ChebyshevU[2, y] LaguerreL[0, 1, x] - 
      6 (ChebyshevU[0, y] LaguerreL[1, 1, x]) + 
      2 (ChebyshevU[0, y] LaguerreL[2, 1, x])]

  -1 + x^2 + y^2
*)
```

Comment: In the definition of `changeBasis` i think `{x, y}` should be `{basisfamilies}[[All, 1]]` or `vars`

Comment: @Coolwater D'oh! Thanks! -- I probably missed replacing it by `vars`.

Answer (score 3):

As another variation, here's another method based on repeated greedy division:

```
Reap[Fold[Block[{q, r}, {q, r} = PolynomialQuotientRemainder[#1, #2, x]; Sow[q]; r] &,
          x^3 + x^2 + x + 1, HermiteH[Range[3, 0, -1], x]]][[-1, 1]] // Reverse
   {3/2, 5/4, 1/4, 1/8}
```

Check:

```
%.HermiteH[Range[0, 3], x] == x^3 + x^2 + x + 1 // Expand
   True
```