# Chebyshev Approximation

Tags: series-expansion, approximation

Is there functionality in *Mathematica* to expand a function into a series with Chebyshev polynomials?

The `Series` function only approximates with Taylor series.

Comment: Do you mean by using the formula's in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/9901005.pdf), specifically [these](http://i.imgur.com/yLRbKa8.png)?  If so, [ChebyshevT](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChebyshevT.html) would be the place to start

Comment: (1) Post a specific example. (2) Have a look at `ChebyshevT` documentation, in particular "Generalizations and Extensions", and "Applications"

Comment: This question applied to `WhitakkerW` may be found here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/98350

Comment: And I got the technique from here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/89692

Comment: [Here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23290/series-expansion-in-terms-of-hermite-polynomials) is another related question with very good answers.

Comment: I recall seeing some examples in The Mathematica Journal many years ago as well.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can just take [Bob Hanlon](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/9362/bob-hanlon)'s [answer](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2006/Aug/msg00165.html) from 2006 directly, and modify the plot just a bit to update it.

```
ChebyshevApprox[n_Integer?Positive, f_Function, x_] := 
  Module[{c, xk}, xk = Pi (Range[n] - 1/2)/n;
   c[j_] = 2*Total[Cos[j*xk]*(f /@ Cos[xk])]/n;
   Total[Table[c[k]*ChebyshevT[k, x], {k, 0, n - 1}]] - c[0]/2];

f = 3*#^2*Exp[-2*#]*Sin[2 #*Pi] &;

ChebyshevApprox[3, f, x] // Simplify

((-(3/4))*((-E^(2*Sqrt[3]))*(Sqrt[3] - 2*x) - 2*x - Sqrt[3])*x*
   Sin[Sqrt[3]*Pi])/E^Sqrt[3]

GraphicsGrid[
 Partition[
  Table[Plot[{f[x], ChebyshevApprox[n, f, x]}, {x, -1, 1}, 
    Frame -> True, Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, 
    PlotRange -> {-2, 10}, 
    Epilog -> Text["n = " <> ToString[n], {0.25, 5}]], {n, 9}], 3], 
 ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Comment: I am having trouble using this with non-pure functions. For example, I can not expand Sin with ChebyshevApprox[3, Sin, x]. It also does not plot anything.

Comment: You can make a pure function out of `Sin`, via `ChebyshevApprox[3, Sin[#] &, x]`.  And the result is a polynomial in `x`, so you would plot it in the normal way:  `Plot[{Sin[x], ChebyshevApprox[3, Sin[#] &, x]}, {x, -1, 1}]` - but for `Sin` only one term survives so you have a linear function.  Going up to `n=4` you get a cubic function and it is indistinguishable on that range.

Answer (score 16):

Here's a way to leverage the Clenshaw-Curtis rule of `NIntegrate` and Anton Antonov's answer, [Determining which rule NIntegrate selects automatically](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26401/determining-which-rule-nintegrate-selects-automatically/96663#96663), to construct a piecewise Chebyshev series for a function.  It also turns out that `InterpolatingFunction` implements a Chebyshev series approximation as one of its interpolating units (undocumented).  With `IntegrationMonitor`, you can save the sampling on the subintervals and use `FourierDCT[]` to convert the function values to Chebyshev coefficients. The error estimate for the integral ($E \approx |I_{n/2}-I_{n}|$) is not exactly the same as an approximation norm, but most numerical procedures have pitfalls.

```
fn = 3*#^2*Exp[-2*#]*Sin[2 #*Pi] &[x];
{ifn, {{series}}} = Reap[
  chebApprox[fn, {x, 0, 2}],             (* see below for code *)
  "ChebyshevSeries"]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.003718, Null}  *)

Plot[{fn, ifn[x]}, {x, 0, 2}, 
 PlotStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[5], Automatic}],
LogPlot[(fn - ifn[x])/fn // Abs, {x, 0, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The reaped `series` are in a list of the form `{{{x1, x2}, {coefficients}},...}`.

```
Short[series, 12]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In this example there are four series over the intervals

```
series[[All, 1]]
(*  {{0, 0.5}, {0.5, 1.}, {1., 1.5}, {1.5, 2}}  *)
```

**Code dump**

```
ClearAll[chebInterpolation];
(* Constructs a piecewise InterpolatingFunction, 
 * whose interpolating units are Chebyshev series *)
(* data0 = {{x0,x1},c1},..} *)
chebInterpolation[data0 : {{{_, _}, _List} ..}] := 
  Module[{data = Sort@data0, domain1, coeffs1, domain, grid, ngrid, 
    coeffs, order, y0, yp0},
   domain1 = data[[1, 1]];
   coeffs1 = data[[1, 2]];
   domain = List @@ Interval @@ data[[All, 1]];
   y0 = chebFunc[coeffs1, domain1, First@domain1];
   yp0 = chebFunc[dCheb[coeffs1, domain1], domain1, First@domain1];
   grid = Union @@ data[[All, 1]];
   ngrid = Length@grid;
   coeffs = data[[All, 2]];
   order = Length[coeffs[[1]]] - 1;
   InterpolatingFunction[
      domain,
      {5, 1, order, {ngrid}, {4; order}, 0, 0, 0, 0, Automatic, {}, {}, False},
      {grid},
      {{y0, yp0}} ~Join~ coeffs,
      {{{{1}}~Join~Partition[Range@ngrid, 2, 1] ~Join~ {{ngrid - 1, ngrid}},
      {Automatic } ~Join~ ConstantArray[ChebyshevT, ngrid]}}] /; 
    Length[domain] == 1 && ArrayQ@coeffs
   ];

Clear[chebApprox];
(* Uses NIntegrate's Clenshaw-Curtis Rule
 * to construct Chebyshev series approximations to a function
 * over the subintervals created by NIntegrate *)
Options[chebApprox] = {"Points" -> 17} ~Join~ Options[NIntegrate]; 
chebApprox[f_, {x_, a_, b_}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{t, samp, sampling},
  With[{pg = OptionValue[PrecisionGoal] /. Automatic -> 14,
    ag = OptionValue[AccuracyGoal] /. Automatic -> 15},
   t = Reap[
     NIntegrate[f, {x, a, b},
      Method -> {"ClenshawCurtisRule", 
        "Points" -> OptionValue["Points"]},
      PrecisionGoal -> pg, AccuracyGoal -> ag,
      IntegrationMonitor :> (Sow[
          Map[{First[#1@"Boundaries"], #1@"GetValues"} &, #1], 
          samp] &),
      Evaluate@FilterRules[{opts}, Options[NIntegrate]]],
     samp];
   sampling = With[{steps = t[[2, 1]]},
     Flatten[
       Table[If[MemberQ[steps[[n + 1]], {{s[[1, 1]], _}, __}], 
         Nothing, s], {n, Length@steps - 1}, {s, steps[[n]]}], 1] ~Join~ 
     DeleteCases[Last@steps, {{-Infinity, Infinity}, __}]
     ];
   sampling = Sort@MapAt[chebSeries@*Reverse, sampling, {All, 2}];
   Sow[sampling, "ChebyshevSeries"];
   chebInterpolation[sampling]
   ]];

chebSeries[y_] := Module[{cc},
  cc = Sqrt[2/(Length@y - 1)] FourierDCT[y, 1]; (* get coeffs from values *)
  cc[[{1, -1}]] /= 2;  (* 
  adjust first & last coeffs *)
  cc
  ]

(* Differentiate a Chebyshev series *)
(* Recurrence: $2 r c_r =  c'_{r-1} - c'_{r+1}$ *)
Clear[dCheb];
dCheb::usage = 
  "dCheb[c, {a,b}] differentiates the Chebyshev series c scaled over \
the interval {a,b}";
dCheb[c_] := dCheb[c, {-1, 1}];
dCheb[c_, {a_, b_}] := Module[{c1 = 0, c2 = 0, c3},
   2/(b - a) MapAt[#/2 &,
     Reverse@ Table[
        c3 = c2;
        c2 = c1; 
        c1 = 2 (n + 1)*c[[n + 2]] + c3,
       {n, Length[c] - 2, 0, -1}],
     1]
   ];
```

Notes and references:

- [Interpolating data with a step](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34228/interpolating-data-with-a-step/98349#98349)
- [What's inside InterpolatingFunction[{{1., 4.}}, <>]?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28337/whats-inside-interpolatingfunction1-4/28341#28341)
- `adaptiveChebSeries` of [Find all roots of a function with parabolic cylinder functions in a range of the variable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86860/find-all-roots-of-a-function-with-parabolic-cylinder-functions-in-a-range-of-the/113950#113950) presents another approach.
- The recurrence for the differentiation of Chebyshev series is probably well-known, but I got it from [Clenshaw and Norton (1963)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/comjnl/6.1.88).
- This approach was suggested by a comment I saw in [Boyd (2013)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/110838297) that an interval could be split in two "whenever the Clenshaw–Curtis strategy calls for $N$ larger then some user-specified limit."  The `"ClenshawCurtisRule"` of `NIntegrate` does not adapt the order $N$ (which equals two times the value of `"Points"` in `NIntegrate`), but it does split the intervals.

One can get a single Chebyshev series by setting `MaxRecursion -> 0`.

```
{{domain}, values} = 
  Reap[NIntegrate[fn, {x, 0, 2}, PrecisionGoal -> 14, 
     AccuracyGoal -> 15,
     Method -> {"ClenshawCurtisRule",
       "Points" -> 1 + 2^5},     (* adjust "Points" to achieve desired accuracy *)
     MaxRecursion -> 0,
     WorkingPrecision -> 40, 
     IntegrationMonitor :> (Sow[
         Map[{#1@"Boundaries", #1@"GetValues"} &, #1]] &)]
    ][[2, 1, 1, 1]];
cs = Module[{n = 1, max, sum = 0, ser, len},
   ser = chebSeries[Reverse@values];
   max = Max[ser];
   len = LengthWhile[Reverse[ser], (sum += Abs@#) < 10^-22*max &];
   Drop[N@ser, -len]
   ];

approx[x_?NumericQ] := 
 cs.Table[ChebyshevT[n - 1, Rescale[x, domain, {-1, 1}]], {n, Length@cs}]    

Plot[{fn, approx[x]}, {x, 0, 2}, 
   PlotStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[5], Automatic}],  
LogPlot[(fn - approx[x])/fn // Abs, {x, 0, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Now, you've previously told me how you discovered the hidden support for piecewise Chebyshev interpolants, but I'm still amazed that we're just about close to having `chebfun` being natively supported. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 15):

One slick way to derive the analytic Chebyshev series of a function is to use the relationship between the Chebyshev polynomials and the cosine, and then use the built-in `FourierCosSeries[]`. As an example:

```
f[x_] := Exp[x];
n = 5; (* degree of approximation *)
approx[x_] = FourierCosSeries[f[Cos[t]], t, n] /. Cos[k_. t] :> ChebyshevT[k, x]
```

(Note that the result of that evaluation contains modified Bessel functions of the first kind, which arise as the coefficients.)

```
{Plot[{f[x], approx[x]}, {x, -1, 1}],
 Plot[approx[x] - f[x], {x, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> ColorData[97, 3]]} // GraphicsRow
```

[image: plot of function and Chebyshev series, and the approximation error]

See how good the approximation is? Note the equiripple behavior of the error at the right.

---

Of course, not every function will admit a closed form Chebyshev series representation, since the Fourier integrals involved won't necessarily have a closed form known to *Mathematica*. In that case, you can of course use `NIntegrate[]` instead. In fact, *Mathematica* does provide a package for numerically evaluating those integrals. Thus,

```
Needs["FourierSeries`"]

f[x_] := 3 x^2 Exp[2 x] Sin[2 π x];

n = 12;
cof = Table[If[k == 0, 1/2, 1] NFourierCosCoefficient[f[Cos[t]], t, k, Method -> "LevinRule"],
            {k, 0, n}];

(* Clenshaw recurrence for a Chebyshev series *)
chebval[c_?VectorQ, x_] := Module[{n = Length[c], u, v, w},
        u = c[[n - 1]] + 2 x (v = c[[n]]); 
        Do[w = v; v = u; u = c[[k]] + 2 x v - w, {k, n - 2, 2, -1}]; 
        c[[1]] + x u - v]

approx[x_] = chebval[cof, x];
{Plot[{f[x], approx[x]}, {x, -1, 1}],
 Plot[approx[x] - f[x], {x, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> ColorData[97, 3]]} // GraphicsRow
```

[image: not too good]

though the approximation in this case is not too good.

Comment: The coefficients can also be computed using `FourierDCT` as shown [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/59097/14295)

Comment: @Stelios, yes, using the discrete cosine transform corresponds to using the trapezoidal rule to discretize the underlying Fourier integrals. The answers linked by Michael in the comments use that strategy as well.