# Solve for coefficients to express polynomial in terms of another polynomial

Tags: equation-solving, special-functions, polynomials

If I have a polynomial, say $p(x) = 6x^3 - x^2 + x$, and I want to express that in terms of a sum of other polynomials, how may I do that in Mathematica? Specifically I would like to say that $$p(x) = \sum_{i = 0}^3 \alpha_i P_i(x)$$ where $P_i(x)$ is the $i^{th}$ Legendre Polynomial (not super important what exactly the other polynomial is).

I have attempted the following:

```
p = 6*x^3 - x^2 + x;
Solve[p == (C3*LegendreP[3, x] + C2*LegendreP[2, x] + 
  C1*LegendreP[1, x] + C0*LegendreP[0, x]), {C3, C2, C1, C0}]
```

but it gives

```
 {{C0 -> x - C1 x - x^2 + 6 x^3 - 1/2 C2 (-1 + 3 x^2) - 
    1/2 C3 (-3 x + 5 x^3)}}
```

as the output when I know (for this example) the C's are real numbers.

Comment: [This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23290) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59089) are related.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please see if this does what you want.

```
p      = 6*x^3 - x^2 + x;
coeff  = CoefficientList[p, x]
p0     = Expand[C3*LegendreP[3, x] + C2*LegendreP[2, x] + C1*LegendreP[1, x] + 
              C0*LegendreP[0, x]];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
coeff0 = CoefficientList[p0, x];
eqs    = Thread[coeff == coeff0];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
sol = First @ Solve[eqs, {C0, C1, C2, C3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To verify

```
 p0 /. sol
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @C.Fuhrman - You have four unknowns so `Solve` needs four equations to determine them. As shown by @Nasser, the four equations are obtained by equating the corresponding coefficients.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a different method using `SolveAlways`:

```
poly = 6 x^3 - x^2 + x
SolveAlways[poly == Sum[C[i] LegendreP[i, x], {i, 0, 3}], x]
```

> {{C[0] -> -(1/3), C[2] -> -(2/3), C[1] -> 23/5, C[3] -> 12/5}}

Answer (score 1):

This is the job of `PolynomialReduce`; see the documentation [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PolynomialReduce.html).

For your example,

```
PolynomialReduce[p, Table[LegendreP[i, x], {i, 0, 3}], {x}]
```

is the idiomatic way. The output is of the form `{coefficientList, remainder}` where in the cases where the reduction is possible, `remainder` is zero.

Comment: This won't work though, because the multipliers can be (and are, in this case) polynomials in 'x'. One can homogenize everything to degree 3 however; that seems to work. Multiplying each degree in `x` by a distinct  new variable is another way to go about this.

Answer (score 1):

The classical method for converting a polynomial to an orthogonal basis is [Salzer's algorithm](https://doi.org/10.1145/355611.362548). Adapted to the Legendre case, here is how to use it for conversion:

```
bb = CoefficientList[6 x^3 - x^2 + x, x]
   {0, 1, -1, 6}

Clear[a]; n = Length[bb] - 1;
a[0, 0] = a[1, 1] = bb[[n + 1]]; a[0, 1] = bb[[n]];
Do[a[0, k + 1] = bb[[n - k]] + a[1, k]/3;
   Do[a[m, k + 1] = (m + 1)/(2 m + 3) a[m + 1, k] + m/(2 m - 1) a[m - 1, k],
      {m, k - 1}];
   a[k, k + 1] = k/(2 k - 1) a[k - 1, k];
   a[k + 1, k + 1] = (k + 1)/(2 k + 1) a[k, k],
   {k, n - 1}];
Table[a[m, n], {m, 0, n}]
   {-1/3, 23/5, -2/3, 12/5}
```

Check:

```
%.LegendreP[Range[0, n], x] // Expand
   x - x^2 + 6 x^3
```

Comment: ([Related math.SE answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/86600))